# How do i handle an exception caused by XAML binding to a static instance property SQL timeout?

Tags: wpf, xaml, exception, binding, connection

I have problem where after loading my app, sometimes my connection to SQL is dropped.  This often results in an error because i have a combobox's itemsource bound to a separate static class property that, inside the GET of the property, queries SQL.  I can't seem to handle the exception inside the Get.  How should I do this, or is querying SQL in the Get of the static property I'm binding to not the way to go?  The GetFrequencies method is in the same static class as the static property, and just queries some stuff from SQL and throws an exception if it can't connect etc.  Here's the basic property and binding:
Property in static class (an instance):

```
public ObservableCollection<Frequency> ActiveFrequencies
        {
            get
            {
                ObservableCollection<Frequency> Actives = new ObservableCollection<Frequency>();
                try
                    {
                        foreach (Frequency item in GetFrequencies(null, null, true))
                        {
                            Actives.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                return Actives;
            }
        }
```

Binding in XAML:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ActiveFrequencies, Source={x:Static G:FrequencyData.Instance}}"
```

okay so i made a property inside my viewmodel instead:

```
public ObservableCollection<Frequency> ActiveFrequencies
        {
            get
            {
                ObservableCollection<Frequency> freqs = null;
                try
                {
                    freqs = FrequencyData.Instance.GetFrequencies(null, null, true);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {

                }
                return freqs;
            }
        }
```

but i stil can't really shutdown the app in the Catch block, it seems to go on to other properties first.  this is a viewmodel for a user control that is inside a main application view model.  do i need to message my main view model to shutdown instead?

Comment: Put that in a proper ViewModel and have the ViewModel call the Data Access Layer, not the UI.

Comment: @HighCore, so you're saying i should just create properties  in my viewmodel and bind to the view model property?

Comment: did that, what to do to handle the exception.  here's what i have now, but it doesn't seem to actually shut down the app right away, it keeps going     see edit above